# Агрегирование mongodb. Получить массив значений приростов значений исходного массива. Это возможно?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

К примеру есть коллекция из документов с числовыми полями N:

```
{ n: 2, name: a },
{ n: 6, name: b },
{ n: 10, name: a },
{ n: 10, name: a },
{ n: 10, name: b },
{ n: 11, name: a },
```

Я могу сгруппировать документы по `name` и положить все значения `n` в массив:

```
Collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$name', values: {$push: '$n'} }} }
])
```

На выходе будет:

```
{ _id: a, values: [2, 10, 10, 11] },
{ _id: b, values: [6, 10] }
```

Вот собственно в чем вопрос! В документации не смог понять что искать и соответственно не нашел.
Мне нужно получить из этих массивов `values` массивы приростов значений, то есть следующие:

```
{ _id: a, values: [2, 8, 0, 1] }

// Ну то есть во таким образом из [2, 10, 10, 11] получить [2, 8, 0, 1]
// ( 2 - null == 2; 10 - 2 == 8; 10 - 10 == 0, 11 - 10 == 1 )
```

Я начал копать в сторону `$reduce`, но там есть доступ только к текущему элементу `'$$this'`  и к аккумулятору `'$$value'`. Если бы можно было получить что то типо `$$this.index` - то норм, но нет( Что делать?

Возможно ли это провернуть средствами mongo db aggregation?
И как?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сам нашел решение, напишу тут, для таких же как я, которые не умеют нормально читать доку)

В монге есть такая штука [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

С ее помощью можно делать сложные аггрегации данных, с помощью нативного JS.
Как я понял, в данном случае мы проигрываем в производительности, ну другого выходу похоже нет. Собственно само решение задачи (mongoose.js):

```
const o: any = {}

// Данная функция группирует документы по полю name и складывает поля n в массив 
1) o.map = 'function() { emit(this.name, this.n); }'

// Тут мы пробегаемся этой функцией по каждому документу: (values - массив и n элементов)
2) o.reduce = `
 function(key, values) {
 redVal = { count: values.length - 1, qty: 0, arr: [] };

 for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++ ) {
   if ( idx > 0) {
     var def = values[idx] - values[idx-1];
     redVal.qty = redVal.qty + def;
   }
 }

 return redVal;
}
`
// Финальная функция: (находим среднее значение)
3) o.finalize = `
  function(key, redVal) {
   redVal.avg = redVal.qty/redVal.count; 
   return redVal;
  }
  `
 4) o.verbose = true  // отображение статистики
 5) o.query = '{}'

  const model = await Product.mapReduce(o)
  Как я понял потом к этой модели можно делать обычные лайтовые запросы или записать данные в новую коллекцию.
```

Решение не самое красивое, тестовый вариант)

Вот [примеры](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/)  из доки.

Примеры из [mongoose.js](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce)